# How do I find the underlying Type of a Fake object returned from FakeItEasy?

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I've done

```
fake1 = A.Fake<MyType>()
```

then I want to use 'reflection' on the fake to register the dependency with my dependency container as MyType. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the underlying faked type. Any pointers?

Comment: I think the question is more about getting back ‛MyType‛, although I'm not sure why it's needed. (From the example, we know it's MyType). @Tim, can you expand a little on what you want and what you want to do with it?

Comment: @BlairConrad I want to be able to pass a collection of fakes into a method which will register everything in the collection with the dependency container.

Comment: @adrianbanks that returned 'Castle.Proxies.something' not my actual type. However, your suggestion turned me on to a working solution!

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith: Glad I was of help. It might be worth posting your answer here so that someone looking for similar in the future can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up with.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
foreach (var obj in fakes)
{
    Type fakedType = obj.GetType().BaseType;
    builder.RegisterInstance(obj).As(fakedType);
}
```

Note that it assumes you are doing virtual method on base class faking, not interface faking, since that currently holds true for me. :)

You could easily extend it with a little more reflection to register the instance as all of its inherited interfaces too...

Comment: I see how that would work for your particular case, with the caveat you mentioned, and others.
I see your comment about passing a collection of fakes, but I think I would've gone with
`builder.RegisterInstance(A.Fake<MyType>()).As<MyType>()` or similar. I'm sure you have good reasons for your approach.

It looks like you're using AutoFac to register FakeItEasy fakes. Have you looked at AutoFac's [FakeItEasy integration](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/FakeItEasy)? I don't know much about it, but it may meet your needs as well.

Comment: @Blair Conrad Thanks for the suggestions.